# Create user after filling wizard form in Meteor.js

Tags: javascript, forms, meteor, meteor-accounts, meteor-autoform

I'm developing a form based app and would love to reduce the clutter. I'm taking the users email and mobile number along with a bunch of other particulars. What I want to implement is a wizard like form and on pressing submit an account is created with the form as an associated db. (it form has loan application details belonging to the user )

I plan on using the mobile number as the users password and the email as the username. How can this be implemented in Meteor. Do I need to implement my own user package or can this be created using or modifying existing packages.

**Note** : I'm trying to avoid adding an entire loan application with many many fields as a part of user model. I'd prefer a different forms db associated with the user (as blogs belong to author). I just don't want a sign up process putting people off before they even begin filling the form.

PS: A general walkthrough would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend you look at the extensive [useraccounts](https://atmospherejs.com/useraccounts/core) package and it's related packages for styling. Have a look at their [official guide here](https://github.com/meteor-useraccounts/core/blob/master/Guide.md). It comes with a few sensible default fields but it is straightforward to add custom ones

```
AccountsTemplates.addField({
    _id: 'phone',
    type: 'tel',
    displayName: "Landline Number",
});
```

If you want to stick with core Meteor packages, [here is an excellent tutorial](http://meteortips.com/second-meteor-tutorial/user-accounts/).

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply mate! Actually I do know using the account packages. I meant how to link a form before creating an account and then on the last submit, create the account using fields from the form. I'm rather not inclined on adding an entire loan application as extra fields on the meteor accounts package

Comment: Well if you configure the form with your custom fields, and then present users with the `{{> atForm}}` template when they want to signup, once they submit that form an account will be created. Am I missing something?

Comment: I  added a note to the original question to explain my intention better.